# send list of data with form data in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this form :

```
    createForm(): void {
    this.addNewsFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        published: [false],
        thumbnail: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        WriterListUserId: [''],
    });
}
```

i need to send list of users in this fild `WriterListUserId` . like this :
`[{title:1,userId:1},{title:1,userId:1},{title:1,userId:1}]`

liek this :

```
WriterListUserId:[{title:1,userId:1},{title:1,userId:1},{title:1,userId:1}]
```

but when i using this code for send data to server :

```
add(item: NewsAddModel): Observable<any> {
    const Url = `${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint}/News`;
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    for (const key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            if (item[key] instanceof File) {
                formData.append(key, item[key], item[key].name);
            } else {
                formData.append(key, item[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return this.http.post<any>(Url, formData, {
        headers: this.headers,
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events'
    })
        .pipe(map(response =>
            response || {} as HttpEvent<any>
        ));
}
```

but it send to server by this :

```
WriterListUserId:[{object object},{object object}]
```

but i need to send to server like this :

```
 WriterListUserId:[{title:1,userId:1},{title:1,userId:1},{title:1,userId:1}]
```

**Whats the Problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

**Update :**

i change the form data to this :

```
if (key === 'WriterListUserId') {
                    formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(item[key]));
                }
```

and it send to server this data :

```
WriterListUserId: [{"title":5,"userId":1},{"title":2,"userId":2}]
```

but stiil not work .

Comment: Please feel to provide a stackblitz demo,  plus formData has some issue with displaying with console's so please check with the network tab

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i realy happy for you are online . i can not create that in stackbliz

Comment: Okay, can you test that API in postman and share the screenshot?

Comment: yes i can . . .

Comment: I think you have to use `FormArray`. Check this guide and stackblitz in the blog post. http://www.howilearnt.com/web-development/angular/make-a-json-object-with-angular-forms/

Comment: @AliWahab i update the question

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i update the question

Comment: @kianoushdortaj That's why, need the postman screenshot - by using that we can identify, how your API is excepting request body!